# Using Power BI Desktop, how can I present Time Duration in a matrix that converts it to decimal?

Tags: time, powerbi, report

I have Begin Date and End Date in my data file (Excel), then in PowerQuery I add a column where I simply subtract the Begin Date from End Date to create a new column "Import Time", change the result's data type to Duration and in PowerQuery, the column correctly shows the difference expressed in Day:Hour:Minute:Seconds. However, in a report, I need to show the average not of an entire column, but of groups of values in a matrix based on the entire table. In other words, I'm looking for a table that shows columns for Category Name, Avg. Duration and Max Duration, with rows showing the results for each unique Category.

The problem is that when I drag a table field in to the Visualizations Value area and change to Average, it expresses the result as a decimal, and I can't figure out how to show the date / time equivalent. I thought I might have to multiply by 3,600 since the result might be shown in milliseconds, but that didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does adjusting Data type and/or Format in the Column tool ribbon tab not work?

Comment: No, it's not as simple as that. In Power Query, the "Import Time" field I created by calculating the difference between End Time and Begin Time is formatted as Duration, or date / time format. When I summarize the information in the Import Time field in a report - to compute the average, in this case - it appears as a decimal, and I can't find anywhere to show that as a date / time format. That is the precise issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I theorized that perhaps the issue wasn't one with Power BI, but perhaps with how Microsoft expresses date / time computations. I edited my Excel file that contains the source data and computed the "Import Time" by subtracting Begin Time from End Time. By default, it displays in date / time format of "hh:mm:ss.0000". I then asked Google and came across a simple explanation: to express a date / time in numeric format, you need to multiply the date / time by 24 (hours), 60 (minutes) and 60 (seconds) if that's how you wanted to express the result. I then created a Pivot Table summarizing the average of the Import Times and saw the same thing I did in my Power BI report, which is when it clicked it for me.

To solve the issue, I edited my Power Query step to compute the import time and included " * 24 * 60 * 60" in the formula. After updating the report, the results matched what I saw in Excel and I'm good. Hopefully this helps others to deal with this vexing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You wrap your averaging measure in a `FORMAT` function to convert it to precisely the text format you want to show in your matrix. For example, suppose your raw output is

```
Group  AvgDuration
------------------
 A      0.0633
 B      0.2733
 C      0.0600
```

These numbers are in the unit of days, so you can convert to hours, minutes, or seconds like this e.g.:

```
FORMAT ( [AvgDuration] * 24, "0.00h" )
FORMAT ( [AvgDuration] * 24 * 60, "#,0m" )
FORMAT ( [AvgDuration] * 24,* 60 * 60, "#,0s" )
FORMAT ( [AvgDuration], "hh:mm:ss" )
```

(where [AvgDuration] is your measure you use to calculate the average)

Those last two should look like this:

```
Group  AvgDuration
------------------
 A      5,472s
 B      23,616s
 C      5,184s
```

and

```
Group  AvgDuration
------------------
 A      01:31:12
 B      06:33:36
 C      01:26:24
```